# Transaction has been reverted by the EVM(Error encountered during contract execution [out of gas] )

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am trying to execute a function from the truffle console and getting the error without much information.

```
contract LPTokenWrapper {
IERC20 public lp_tkn = IERC20(0xf7a35Eef60dC35fa2D3188Dfb22e635E4308fc8b);
function stake(uint256 amount) public {
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
        _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].add(amount);
        tkn.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    }
}
```

from truffle console doing(with the same account which has lp_tkn) `lp_wrp.stake(web3.utils.toWie("1"));`

https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x2eba99c94ba96513794da6e10e1c88d80e3ca619b13fc994428abc0e6fa2fd4c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that `address(this)` is not *authorised* to `transferFrom()` funds that belong to `msg.sender`. It can't simply help itself to someone else's tokens.

In the ERC20 standard, the user is required to `approve()` - allow the receiver, which is the contract, to take a certain amount of tokens *before* the receiver can use `transferFrom()`. This is usually coordinated by the UI so the user just signs the authorizing transaction.

Importantly, the transaction *must be* from the user directly, not via a smart contract, sent directly to the ERC20 token contract.

The Open Zeppelin implementation:

```
    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-approve}.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }
```

So, the user will send a transaction to the ERC20 contract to `approve` a certain address, your contract, to `transferFrom()` a certain amount of tokens from the user - the allowance. Then, your contract will be able to `transferFrom()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I am getting one more issue while calling ```getreward()``` function error is ```SafeERC20: low-level call failed``` any about this also?